# How to find $E\left[\frac{1}{\bar{X}}\right]$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, maximum-likelihood

Given $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n \sim X$ where

$$f_X(x;\theta) = \theta^2 xe^{-\theta x}, \quad x>0,\quad\theta >0$$

I was able to find the expectation $E[X]=\frac{2}{\theta }$ and that the MLE is $\hat{\theta} = \frac{2}{\bar{X}}$.

I am asked to see if this MLE is unbiased、so my instinct is to evaluate

$$E\left[\frac{2}{\bar X}\right]$$
but I am not comfortable with the $\bar X$ being on the denominator like that . . .

Can someone help me out with how to find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jensen inequality you can deduce that 
$$
\mathbb{E} [2/\bar{X} ] \ge2/\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = \theta,
$$ 
i.e., 
$$
\mathbb{E} \hat{\theta}-\theta\ge0.
$$
And if you are interested in explicit calculations then note that $2/\bar{X} = 2n/\sum X_i $, where $\sum X_i \sim Erlang(2n, \theta) $, thus 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=2n \int\frac{\theta^{2n}}{y \Gamma(2n)} e^{-\theta y} y ^ {2n-1}dy = \theta\frac{2n}{2n-1} \ge \theta  
$$

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much for the concise and apropos answer.

Comment: I did a bit more research and realized that the Erlang Distribution is one of the special cases of a Gamma Distribution.  That was truly helpful, thank you!!